# Escaping characters in JQuery ID element in ui widget

Tags: jquery, escaping

I'm trying to use the JQuery autocomplete select with an ID with ":" in it's name
on this link you can find my problem:
[JSfiddleShortLink](http://jsfiddle.net/Alch3mi5t/gW4UE/1/)

the piece of code is:

```
   $(function() {
    $( "#sc\\:combobox" ).sc:combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
        $( "#sc\\:combobox" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if after the `$( "#sc\\:combobox" ).` I should escape again the ":"
and is this valid also in the JQuery function on top of the link

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.sc:combobox", {
        _create: function() {etc
```

Could you give me some hints?
I'm pretty stuck.
I would prefer not to use the replace function if possible.
Just need to figure out where to escape and where not.
P.S. If I replace the code "sc:combobox" with "combobox" the selection is working perfectly
as here:
[JSFiddleWorking](http://jsfiddle.net/Alch3mi5t/gW4UE/)

thank you guys!
A.

Answer (score 0):

A single backslash should do the trick

```
$( "#sc\:combobox" )
```

Comment: where exactly?Did you see the jsfiddle code?
It doesn't seems to be working.